# Adobe AIR - SQLite - Multiple Clients

Tags: sqlite, air, adobe

I have a commercial Point Of Sale product that's written on Adobe AIR and runs in about 100 retail locations right now.  Most of my customers have about 5 computers in the store.  Some of my larger customers have 10-20 computers.

The application currently uses the embedded SQLite database to persist data.  I made a huge technical mistake early on and some of my larger clients are having problems. I'm wondering if anyone can provide some ideas on how to get around the problem. Here it is...

The application runs in Master and Workstation modes.  In the Master mode, the database resides on the physical machine.  In Workstation mode, the application accesses the database over the network.  SQLite is not intended to be used in this fashion and it's causing all kinds of issues (file locking, data disappearing, files being corrupted, etc).

I've been racking my brain on how to resolve this issue without completely rewriting the application.  I have nice separation of concerns in the application so I do have the ability to re-write the data layer.

Here are some of the requirements:
1) The application must run offline
2) The solution must be able to handle transactions
3) The solution must support synchronous connections

Some of the ideas I've had are:

1) Write a "database server" that sits in front of the DB and allows only 1 statement to run at a time.
2) Change out the database to MySQL and utilize the assql library.  I do not believe that this supports synchronous statements.

What ideas do you have?

Thank you!

Comment: you can create a MySQL database and store it with php, but assuming there isn't a mysql and/or php server in the local network, you could connect the workstations to the master and let the master do the database-actions. The workstations could enqueue database-actions on the server. This way you only have 1 active sqlite connection in a network.